# handling empty string for boolean by coalesce in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, boolean, coalesce

Have a code

```
select coalesce(ex.MktShrExclude,'') <> 'true' 
from Market ex;
```

column MktShrExclude is Boolean type

but getting an error

> invalid input syntax for type boolean: ""

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as the error message states: an empty string is not a valid boolean value. You can e.g. use `false`

```
select coalesce(ex.MktShrExclude, false) <> true
from Market ex;
```

Or the null safe `is distinct from`

```
select ex.MktShrExclude is distinct from true
from Market ex;
```